# How to compress data by taking the average of every n rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have some wind data with 8640 rows per year and I am trying to compress it by taking the average wind speed/wind direction of every 30 rows while keeping the date as it is. For the time, I think its best to have a range (`0:00:00 - 0:04:50` for the first row). I am using a tibble and pipes `%>%`.

```
Date Time Wind.Speed wind.direction
20201229    0:00:00 2   272 
20201229    0:00:10 2   272 
20201229    0:00:20 2   284 
20201229    0:00:30 2   284 
20201229    0:00:40 3   284 
20201229    0:00:50 3   261 
20201229    0:01:00 2   261 
20201229    0:01:10 3   261 
20201229    0:01:20 2   255 
20201229    0:01:30 3   255
```

Comment: be careful with that approach - you may loose a lot of valuable information. 9000 rows per year doesn't seem very much too me - even if it is 1000 years, this would be "only" 9x10^6 rows, which is not extremely big

Comment: (to extend on this - you may need time series analysis for that type of data - there are different methods to average over certain periods of time, such as rolling averages) - have a look at the zoo package

Comment: also very related https://stackoverflow.com/q/6903747/7941188

Comment: @tjebo Thank you for your comments. This is something an Electrical Engineering professor requested from me - I will pass the comments on.

Comment: even professors are also not always right... ;) neither am I for that sake

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible solution with a toy `df`:

```r
df <- tibble(Wind.speed = runif(8640), group_row = rep(c(1:(8640/30)), each = "30"))

df %>% 
  group_by(group_row) %>% 
  summarise(mean(Wind.speed))
```

Answer (score 1):

U can try something like this:

```
df %>% 
group_by(group = row_number() %/% 31) %>%
summarise(
 starting_date = first(Date),
 ending_date = last(Date),
 starting_time = first(time),
 ending_time = last(time)
 Wind.speed = mean(Wind.speed), 
 wind.direction = mean(wind.direction),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could also use `base R` with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(Wind.speed ~ group_row, df, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```